# Singleton to model user on iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, oop, design-patterns

I'm working on an app that will need a user to be logged in. I've been thinking about the ways to design the User class and it seems to me like a singleton with a `private init` would be the ideal solution, since it would be accessible code wide and could work together with NSUserDefaults for storing when the app goes into background. However I've read a bunch about singletons and some people seem to seem think they should almost never be used.

Does my use case scenario call for the use of a singleton? Should it be avoided? If so, what are the common design patterns used when writing a single-user app?

Comment: The use of singletons are generally discouraged because of difficulty with testing, creating a user object and passing it around your app through view controller properties is typically used instead.

Comment: singleton is a design pattern so it respond to a given problematic. So for you in your design you should be able to answer to two question : 
- what is my problematic
- why i should use singleton as a solution for my problem

Comment: -Problematic: I need a way to allow only one user to be on the app at a time while being accessible throughout my ViewControllers

-Singletons would be a good choice because they're global and do allow private initalization.

Comment: i disagree with iOS developers who's says should never used because there is no dependency between design patterns and languages or technologies  used

Comment: for your problematic, that's mean that in your application there is a way to have two user in the same time?

Comment: @Paulw11 I think I've just understood why singletons aren't like, because then all of my controllers + code would be entirely dependent on that one super object and would break if it went away, which isn't very oop

Comment: It is ok for classes to depend on other classes but the problem with singletons is because they are initialised as a "side effect" when the first access is made to the shared instance it can be non-deterministic as to when the object is instantiated and it can also be difficult to mock an object for testing

Comment: @Paulw11it's true that singleton is very complicated to test but i think there is many tutorial and blog that explain how to do to test it.

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite i think for your problematic you can use a singleton if you think that it will simplify your code and respond to your needs.

Comment: Even Apple use singleton in iOS SDK, so why we shouldn't use it for our developments ;)

Comment: @Paulw11 Isn't that problem solved by calling a proxy method to trigger init in say `didLaunchWithOptions:` ? For example an empty `func awake(){}`

Comment: I like to use singletons especially when users are concerned. It makes sense to me that a model that represents the user identity gets initialized only once, and persists during the runtime. There are many benefits to this approach, depending on the requirements of your project.

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite yes, you can do that, but it doesn't address the issue that the singleton is an implied dependency for a class rather than an explicit dependency. Search for singleton vs dependency injection.

Comment: It's hard to find any documentation that explains why we should all be so scared of using singletons.  It's not good enough to just say their use is discouraged without explaining why!  For a single user example like this, it looks like an ideal application of this design pattern.

Comment: @Paulw11: What would the problem be if I passed around my singleton instance instead of referencing it in my controllers? This way I remain flexible and testable while having the comfort of the singleton

Comment: If you do this then there is no need for it to be a singleton. It is just an object instance that you create and pass around.

Answer (score 0):

I will use singleton if the app allows one and only one user to login at a time.

1 - Singleton will ensure that the state of the Logged in User object is retrieve and updated from a single shared instance.

2 - Logged In User Class will not have multiple instances, which is good from memory perspective.